# Read/Write a single byte of a void* variable

Tags: c++, c, malloc, void-pointers, memset

If I have

```
void *temp = malloc(128);
memset(temp, 0 , 128);
```

And I want to read the first byte alone, following is what I'm doing.

```
char a[2];
strncpy(a, (char*)temp, 1);
int p = a[0];
//p will be zero in this case
```

**Q1.** I'm sure there is a more elegant way to achieve the same. If so, what would it be?

**Q2.** Is there a way I can alter the value of that single byte alone?

Say I want the first byte to have the value equivalent to the int value 48 (i.e. 00110000)
How would I do that?
I was able to make no progress with the write.

Comment: just make it `char *temp`

Comment: Assume I do not have that freedom and the line void *temp = malloc(128); is pretty much something I'm stuck with

Comment: I see what you did there. Why did I not think of that! 
Please add your comment as an answer since this solved my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can cast it to `char *` then access the memory

```
char *buff = temp;
char p = buff[0]; // read first byte
```

Comment: You don't even need another variable (although it will get optimized away):  you can use `(char*)temp` (in C) or `static_cast<char*>(temp)` (in C++).

Comment: @thirtythreeforty(char*)temp would typecast it to char array. But would I be able to do bytewise manipulation with that? (char*)temp[0] seemed like the logical equivalent but is wrong. Is there a way to alter the first byte using (char*)temp?

Comment: `((char*)void_ptr)[0]`

Comment: I would use `*ptr` syntax instead of `ptr[0]` syntax, eg: `char p = *((char*)temp);` or `char p = *(static_cast<char*>(temp));`